Banner clicks and page location
Banner clicks and impressions for a magazine page of website
I have been trying to implement tags for the banner clicks . There are six different banners on multiple magazine articles when clicked this lead to respect country website.
I have implemented tag and tracking using clock classes . But still I see only two banners are tracking and and able to see which website magazine page are users click. Even after passing a event parameter or page path in a tag
Thanks
Implemented tags with page path event parameters
Implemented trigger with click class of the images with different numbers using regex match

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
